# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'store.getState()')

Tags: react-native, react-redux

so i'm trying to build a simple pages that ask an input and provides a button. when the button pressed, the pages should alert the value of the input. but not taking the value from the inputbox..

so the value of the inputbox, should be saved at redux store and when alerted, the value is taken from the store.

but when I run my codes, it throws me an error saying undefined is not a function

this is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class tes extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        state = {
            phoneNumber: "",
        }
    }

    login() {
        this.props.onLogin(this.state.phoneNumber)
        alert(this.props.reducer.phoneNumber)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder="phone number"
                    keyboardType="number-pad" onChangeText={phoneNumber => this.setState({ phoneNumber })}/>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login}>
                    <Text>login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )}
}

mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        number: state.reducer
    }
}

mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onLogin: (number) => {
            dispatch({
                type: "LOGIN",
                payload: number
            })
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(tes);
```

at the action class:

```
export default function setLoginNumber(number) {
    return{
        type: "LOGIN",
        payload: number
    };
}
```

this is my reducer class :

```
 const reducer = (state = {
    phoneNumber: '',
},action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "LOGIN":
            state = {
                phoneNumber: action.payload
            }
            break;
    }
    return state;
}

export default reducer;
```

and my store class where I create the store using redux:

```
import { createStore , applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducer from './Reducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = () => {
    return createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
}

export default store
```

here is the error shown from the emulator

[the error from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVCXX.png)

can anybody help me with this error? thanks in advance

Comment: what are you doing in your last file where you are creating the store. Remove the [ at the beginning and ][1] from the end

Comment: no, it's a miss click when I try to attach a photo.. sorry

Comment: Are you really enclose all you components in Provider? (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store)

Comment: yup, I wrap my tes class with Provider in the index.js when I call the pages.